# How to check that an user inputted number isn't bigger than LLONG_MAX or LOWER than LLONG_MIN?

Tags: c, limits

I want to check if an user inputted number is bigger or lower than the told values.

I know about [atoll function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) but it doesn't seem to be specially helpful, basing the check on a undefined value doesn't look too convincing.

I also know that I could check if the string the user has inputted is all digits, in this case I could check for things as if the length of the string is bigger than the length of `LLONG_MAX` or `LLONG_MIN` once 0s on the left are removed, or in the case the length of both is the same I could go checking digit by digit and if the value of the inputted number in that digit is bigger than the value of `LLONG_MAX` or `LLONG_MIN` the it would be out of range.

But I guess there has to be a better way to do this. Hope you can give me tips about which that way is.

Comment: you can subtract values from LLONG_MAX digit by digit, when result is negative, then you have a hit. still you need to be careful not to overflow it by subtracting a single digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `strtoll` function instead.

In case the inputted value is out of range, `errno` is set to `ERANGE` and either `LLONG_MIN` or `LLONG_MAX` are returned, depending on whether the value underflows or overflows.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll):

> The  `strtol()` function returns the result of the conversion, unless
>   the    value would underflow or overflow.  If an  underflow  occurs, 
>   `strtol()`    returns  `LONG_MIN`.   If  an overflow occurs, `strtol()`
>   returns `LONG_MAX`.    In both cases, `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.  Precisely
>   the  same  holds  for    `strtoll()`  (with  `LLONG_MIN`  and  `LLONG_MAX` 
>   instead  of  `LONG_MIN`  and    `LONG_MAX`).

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtol`.  Per [the `strtol` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoll.html):

> If the correct value is outside the range of representable values,
>   `{LONG_MIN}`, `{LONG_MAX}`, `{LLONG_MIN}`, or `{LLONG_MAX}` shall be
>   returned (according to the sign of the value), and `errno` set to
>   `[ERANGE]`.

So:

```
errno = 0;
long long result = strtoll( inputStr, NULL, 0 );
if ( ( LLONG_MAX == result ) && ( ERANGE == errno ) )
{
    /* handle error */
   ...
}
```