# Checking overflow long long in C

Tags: c, overflow, long-long

I want to check variable from `fgets` isn't overflowing `ling long int` in C language.
I tried this:

```
long long x; 
fgets(...)
...
if(x <= LLONG_MAX && x >= LLONG_MIN)
```

but it is not working because `long long int` will receive too large number; it
goes back to `LLONG_MIN` + excess (I think so).

Comment: Really?  Just this little bit of non-code?  How about reading the [help] and a [mcve]?

Comment: How could `x` possibly be out of range of the type limits, unless its type range is greater than `long long`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40406986/2410359

Comment: `long long int` is a lot of memory. You are definitely not going to recieve a _too large number_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strtoll` when you are trying to convert from char* to long long. These lines are take from strtoll documentation ([strtoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll)) :

> The strtol() function returns the result of the conversion, unless the value would underflow or overflow. If an underflow occurs, strtol() returns LONG_MIN. If an overflow occurs, strtol() returns LONG_MAX. In both cases, errno is set to ERANGE. Precisely the same holds for strtoll() (with LLONG_MIN and LLONG_MAX instead of LONG_MIN and LONG_MAX).